# update specific column of a specific row - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have this jquery code

```
console.log($('#tr-' + notificationInstanceId));
```

return

```
n.fn.init [a#tr-fg, context: document, selector: "#tr-fg"]
```

It showed you that the select works.

Now, I want to update the 6th column of that row - so I did

```
$('#tr-' + notificationInstanceId).find('td').eq(6).hide;
$('#tr-' + notificationInstanceId).find('td:eq(1)').eq(6).hide;
```

nothing seems to work. What did I do wrong?

## HTML

```
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>

        <td>
            <a href="/a/OS/iii/1?instanceId=OS&amp;ip=1.1.1.1&amp;port=8008&amp;h=509A4CDB9AB2&amp;nae=OS&amp;nodeName=B-Z" id="tr-OS">
                OS
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>2</td>

        <td>
            8.4 GB
        </td>

        <td> NA </td>
        <td class="state-OS">running</td>
        <td>

        </td>

    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td>2</td>

        <td>
            <a href="/a/bu-uu/iii/1?instanceId=bu-uu&amp;ip=1.1.1.1&amp;port=8008&amp;h=509A4CDB9AB2&amp;nae=bu-uu&amp;nodeName=B-Z" id="tr-bu-uu">
                bu-uu
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>0</td>

        <td>
            0.0 GB
        </td>

        <td> NA </td>
        <td class="state-bu-uu">not instantiated</td>
        <td>
        </td>

    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td>3</td>

        <td>
            <a href="/a/fg/iii/1?instanceId=fg&amp;ip=1.1.1.1&amp;port=8008&amp;h=509A4CDB9AB2&amp;nae=fg&amp;nodeName=B-Z" id="tr-fg">
                fg
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>0</td>

        <td>
            0.0 GB
        </td>

        <td> NA </td>
        <td class="state-fg">not instantiated</td>
        <td>

        </td>

    </tr>



</tbody>
```

Comment: Please note that the sixth column will have `columnIndex === 5`.

Comment: @connexo - I will try 5.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Okay I will add that.

Comment: it looks like `#tr-fortiGate` is an `<a>` element, not `<tr>`. Can you add the HTML?

Comment: @Barmar It is an `a` inside a `tr` -

Comment: @Taplar I update that to `hide()` but the selection seems to be the issue. So nothing is hiding at the moment -

Comment: @connexo I change the index to ,5,4,3,2,1 and nothing seems to hide not working. I think the way I select it is completely off.

Comment: @Taplar I have the id in the `a`

Comment: Which is not the parent of a `td`.  `find()` searches for (in)direct children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.find()` is for finding descendants of an element. The 6th column of the table is not a descendant of `#tr-fortiGate`. You need to go up to the containing `<tr>`, then find the desired child of that.

Using a class selector is a little better than hard-coding a column number, IMHO. It allows you to rearrange the columns without having to update the code.

```
$("#tr-" + notificationIsntanceId).closest("tr").children("td[class^=state-]")
```